# Ocaml: Longest Path

Tags: path, ocaml, breadth-first-search

I have to make an algorithm for the longest path problem.

I have an oriented weighted graph, a start node, a stop node and a number k.

The algorithm have to say if , on the graph, exist a path from start node to stop node with at least length k.

The true problem is that i have to use the BFS-visit algortihm and not the DFS. On Ocaml the BFS use the Queue and the node are insert on the end of the structure:

```
    let breadth_first_collect graph start =
        let rec search visited = function
             [] -> visited
             | n::rest -> if List.mem n visited
                then search visited rest
                else search (n::visited) (rest @ (succ graph n))
                (* new nodes are put into queue *)
in search [] [start];;
```

Someone can give me some advise, even theorical to make this?

Answer (score 2):

In a BFS you basically shouldn't recurse deeper before you finished current layer. That means that on each step you should take a set of successors, cut the data, and afterwards recurse into each one in a row. Here is a first approximation (untested) of the algorithm:

```
let breadth_first_collect succ graph start =
  let rec search visited v =
    let succs = succ graph v |>
                List.filter (fun s -> List.mem s visited) in
    List.map (search (succs @ visited)) succs |> List.concat in
  search [] start
```

So, we first visit all children (aka `succs`) prepend the to the queue, and the recursively descent into each child in a row.

Again this is a first approximation. Since you need to know the path length it means, that you need to store each path in your queue separately, and can't just have a set of all visited vertices. That means, that your queue must be `vertex list list`. In that case, you can collect all possible paths, and find if there exists one, that is larger than `k`.